# calling jquery ajax to consume WebMethod from external js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
$.ajax(
   {
       type: "POST",
       url: "Default.aspx/GetAge",
       data: "{}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=uft-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (rsp) { SetAge(rsp); },
       error: function (rsp)
       {
           alert(rsp); 
       }
   });
```

Right now it reports the following error: "Cannot locate the resource". I figure that I am specifying the url incorrectly. This javascript is in an external file located in the same directory as Default.aspx ... any thoughts?

Comment: Is an HTTP request actually being made? Try using Fiddler to see the precise URL being requested. If you've not used Fiddler before, this article is a good introduction - http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111208-1.shtml

Comment: @scott mitchell +1 for useful debugging tool! I am a moron, I needed to clean my build and rebuild.

Comment: Besides Fiddler Firebug is also wonderful tool.

Comment: It sound's like this is not a jQuery problem and maybe a problem with how your WebMethod is setup, http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ might be helpful for you

Comment: Oops looks like you answered this before I posted, glad you got it working.

Comment: what error you are getting?? Are u sure this url 'Default.aspx/GetAge' is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your URL is incorrect - you are using relative url and they are treated by browser as relative to current page. It is not considered relative to js file. For example, if your are trying this request from a page at say `www.xyz.com/SomeFolder/page1.aspx` then your ajax request would get directed to `www.xyz.com/SomeFolder/Default.aspx/GetAge` so adjust the url accordingly.

If possible, use urls in form such as `/services/Default.aspx/GetPage` - note leading slash - they will be always get translated into `<your domain>/services/Default.aspx/GetPage` irrespective of page from which you are invoking them..